# Swifterでの認証完了後の画面遷移方法（Twitter,Firestore)

Tags: swift, ios, firebase

[teratail](http://teratail.com/questions/225081)でも質問した内容ですが、こちらでも質問させて頂きます。

**【実現したいこと】**
Swifterを使用して、Twitterでのログイン機能を実装しています。
認証完了後、次のViewへ遷移させたいのですが、どのようにやれば良いのか分からないでいます。
ご教示頂けませんでしょうか。

**【エラー内容】**
下記コードで画面遷移をさせたいです。
現在のコードですと、下記画面で認証完了した後に、元の画面に戻ってしまいます。

```
self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "gotoMain", sender: self)
```

[image: Twitter認証画面]

**【該当コード】**

```swift
import UIKit
import Firebase
import Swifter
import SafariServices

class LoginViewController: UIViewController, SFSafariViewControllerDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var emailTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var passwordTextField: UITextField!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    @IBAction func twitterLoginButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let swifter = Swifter(consumerKey: "consumerKeyを記載",consumerSecret: "consumerSecretを記載")
        swifter.authorize(withCallback: URL(string: "コールバックURL")!, presentingFrom: self,
                          success: {accessToken, response in

                            guard let accessToken = accessToken else {
                                return
                            }
                            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "gotoMain", sender: self)
                            let oAuthToken = accessToken.key
                            let secret = accessToken.secret
                            let credential = TwitterAuthProvider.credential(withToken: oAuthToken, secret: secret)
                            Auth.auth().signIn(with: credential, completion: { (authResult, error) in   
                            })
        }, failure: { error in print(error)
        })
    }
}
```

**【参考記事】**
[【iOS】TwitterKitじゃなくて「Swifter」でTwitterログインする](https://qiita.com/k-boy/items/c83a0505d12cc8e7d4b9#firebase%E3%81%A7%E3%83%AD%E3%82%B0%E3%82%A4%E3%83%B3%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B)

Comment: 回答される方へ　https://teratail.com/questions/225081

Comment: 質問への「タグ」は独立した機能として存在しているので、タイトルに【】等を用いた "タグのようなもの" を独自に付けることは推奨されません。詳しくは [該当のヘルプ](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) も参考にしてください。

Answer (score 0):

xcode11からSceneDelegate.swiftが追加され、これまでAppDelegateに記述されていたコードの多くが、SceneDelegateに移行されました。

その結果、appで他のurlを開いた場合に実行される関数も、AppDelegateからSceneDelegateに移行されています。

以下の記事を参考に、再度コードを見直してみることは、問題解決の助けになるかもしれません。

[【iOS13】swifterを用いた際のcallback URLのSceneDelegateへの記述 - Qiita](https://qiita.com/ninoko1995/items/05de90350a4bbc12d971)